# How to remove dead menus from visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I have some old non-working menu giving me COM error in visual studio 2017 right click menu. I want to get rid of this menu. but not sure how to. This is pointing to EditorContextMenus.CodeWindow.LocateinSolutionExplorer command. This command is dead now. How to clean up this menu?

[image: Visual studio 2017 dead menu of "Located in Soljtion Explorer"]